# Longest common substring in a text that is inside a list of strings

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've come across a problem that similar to the Longest Common Substring problem but with a modification. It's as follows:

A list of strings `lst` and a string `text` are provided. The string may or may not contain substrings that are present in the list. I need the *first* longest substring of `text` that is inside `lst`, considering that you start checking `text` *from the back*. What I mean by *first* and *from the back* is that you start iterating over `text` from the last word, match the longest substring, and return after you encounter a character that breaks the substring match.

For example, if

```
lst = ['abcd', 'x', 'xy', 'xyz', 'abcdxyz']
text = 'abcd abcd xyz xyz'
```

Then the answer would be the last `xyz` in the text because you start checking from the back of `text`, it's inside `lst`, and it is a substring of `text`.

- `'abcd'` is not the answer because it comes before `xyz` in `text`
- `'abcdxyz'` is not the answer because it's a subsequence in `text`

Also, in `text`, substrings can be separated by any character that isn't inside `[A-Za-z]`, but usually they are separated by spaces.

I need an algorithm that solves this. Pseudocode or a Python program would do.

Some test cases

```
lst = ['brisbane', 'east brisbane', '2 street east']
text = '2 street east brisbane'
# answer is east brisbane

lst = ['brisbane', 'east brisbane', '2 street east']
text = '2 street east east brisbane brisbane xyz'
# answer is brisbane

lst = ['sale', 'yarrabilba']
text = 'sale yarrabilba'
# answer is yarrabilba

lst = ['sale', 'yarrabilba']
text = 'abc fgh xyz'
# answer is None

text = 'A Street Name Some Words Suburb Name' 
lst = ['A Street Name', 'Suburb Name']
# answer is 'Suburb Name'

text = 'A Street Name Some Words Name Suburb Name' 
lst = ['A Street Name', 'Suburb Name', 'Name']
# answer is 'Suburb Name'
```

Comment: is performance a requirement?

Comment: Time complexity less than O(n^2) would be preferable. No space requirements

Comment: Why do you need to start iterating from the back? and by character? are the separators always present?

Comment: please give a few typical ut cases.

Comment: In the original problem, `text` can be a string like `'A Street Name Some Words Suburb Name'`, and `lst` can be `['A Street Name', 'Suburb Name']`, then I would like to match `'Suburb Name'` only. It is not possible that  `'A Street Name'` comes after `'Suburb Name'`

Comment: please give a few **unit tests**, just post those functions in your question.

Comment: your "brisbane" example doesn't match the requirement of "last", eventually this would be OK to get `'east brisbane'` for `'2 street east east brisbane xyz'`. Else this is in contradiction with your `abcd`/`xyz` example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use your better example of the comments:

> In the original problem, text can be a string like `'A Street Name Some Words Suburb Name'`, and lst can be `['A Street Name', 'Suburb Name']`,
> then I would like to match `'Suburb Name'` only. It is not possible that
> `'A Street Name'` comes after `'Suburb Name'`

The task would be easy if you had to find the first match of the sentence, you could use a regex and `re.finditer`. Then, let's rework the input by inverting the words and do this!

```
text = 'A Street Name Some Words Suburb Name'
lst  = ['A Street Name', 'Suburb Name']

import re

# define a helper function to reverse words
rev = lambda x: ' '.join(reversed(x.split()))

# invert words in the query
txet = rev(text)
# 'Name Suburb Words Some Name Street A'

# invert words in the searched strings
tsl  = [rev(e) for e in sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True)]
# ['Name Street A', 'Name Suburb']

# find "first" match    
m = re.finditer('|'.join(tsl), txet)
try:
    out = rev(next(m).group())
except StopIteration:
    out = None
```

output: `'Suburb Name'`

example #2:

```
lst = ['brisbane', 'east brisbane', '2 street east']
text = '2 street east east brisbane xyz'
```

output #2: `'east brisbane'`

Comment: In the additional text cases that I added, it returns the answer as `'brisbane'` instead of `'east brisbane'`

Comment: @qk2905 can you edit your question with a set of examples? You can craft the regex to avoid such cases by ordering the strings to match in a specific order

Comment: @qk2905 I updated the answer but is doesn't match all the cases you provided as IMO the second "brisbane" one conflicts with your initial requirement.

Comment: Apologies, the answer I gave for that example was incorrect. I've edited it

Comment: @qk2905 no worries, so it should work now ;)

Comment: Thanks, your answer now passes every test but returns a `StopIteration` error in the one where there is no substring of `text` inside `lst` i.e. the 4th example. I can solve that myself  , otherwise you can update your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def findstem(arr):
 
    # Determine size of the array
    n = len(arr)
 
    # Take first word from array
    # as reference
    s = arr[0]
    l = len(s)
 
    res = ""
 
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i + 1, l + 1):
 
            # generating all possible substrings
            # of our reference string arr[0] i.e s
            stem = s[i:j]
            k = 1
            for k in range(1, n):
 
                # Check if the generated stem is
                # common to all words
                if stem not in arr[k]:
                    break
 
            # If current substring is present in
            # all strings and its length is greater
            # than current result
            if (k + 1 == n and len(res) < len(stem)):
                res = stem
 
    return res
```